# Phone gap install error

Tags: cordova

I installed phone gap by command:
 sudo npm install -g phonegap

Then when I create app as follows:
 phonegap creat firstphoneapp

Error:

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'plist-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.   (/Users/XXXX/.nodebrew/node/v0.10.21/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:20:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

Comment: Don't use sudo for installing cordova/phonegap. Try to do the install without it.

Comment: have you succeeded by entering following command: phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld. Or have you tried to install cordova(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/)

Comment: @Jia Xiao Has your issue been solved? If you have, please share your solution or accept an answer.